# How to determine if login failed due to not accepted cookies in grails

Tags: session, grails, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

In my grails application using shiro, I'm using cookies to store the session data including authorization.

When a user tries to log in without accepting cookies, the login works, but then (as expected) the session is lost again and the user is logged out.

I don't want to change this behavior in general, I just want to display a notification to the user that his Browser needs to accept cookies.

So is there a way to tell that this user has been the one who TRIED to log in after the session data is lost, so that I can display a respective message?

I think running a test whether cookies are accepted on every page is a bit too much, therefore I'm heading towards the solution at login only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the grails session to store the current state of the user.  Then, on login, check the grails session and determine whether to show your message or not.